# iText7 unable to setup logging

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7, common.logging

I'm trying to use `PdfCleanUpTool` with iText7.
However my final PDF is corrupted (it is only 15B in size).

When I start my **console** app from VS I get this in Output:

> no configuration section  found - suppressing logging output

I'm trying to setup logging to get error message, but without luck.

I've installed this packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Common.Logging" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.Core" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.NLog4412" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="itext7" version="7.1.2" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="itext7.pdfsweep" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.4.12" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Portable.BouncyCastle" version="1.8.1.3" targetFramework="net47" />
</packages>
```

and this is my `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog4412">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:MM\:ss} ${logger} ${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Probably I need to setup a license key, but I'd like to get error message saying that I must so.

My question is:
How should I correctly setup **NLog** with **Common.Logging** to get errors from **iText7**.

Here is full example that can be used to verify current behavior:

```
using Common.Logging;
using Common.Logging.Configuration;
using Common.Logging.Simple;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.PdfCleanup;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace RedactTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection
            {
                ["showDateTime"] = "true",
                ["level"] = "All"
            };

            LogManager.Adapter = new ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);

            using (Stream inputStream = new FileStream("D:\\test.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
                using (Stream outputStream = new FileStream("D:\\test_redact.pdf", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
                    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

                    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new List<PdfCleanUpLocation>
                    {
                        new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(40f, 650f, 200f, 700f),ColorConstants.GRAY),
                        new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(40f, 550f, 200f, 590f),ColorConstants.GRAY),
                        new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(344f, 650f, 550f, 724f),ColorConstants.GRAY)
                    };

                    PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, cleanUpLocations);
                    cleaner.CleanUp();
                }
            }
            Console.Write("OK");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to log informations into a file and not to the console?

Comment: @LenglBoy yes, without luck

Comment: And there your configuration was complete like [here in the tutorial](https://brutaldev.com/post/logging-setup-in-5-minutes-with-nlog)

Comment: @LenglBoy NLog isn't a problem, I've used it before many times. I can' t configure `Common.Logging` and `NLog` to work together. I need this to get messages from `iText 7`

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question?

Comment: @mkl is is sample I downloaded from the internet: https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf

Comment: @Misiu I could reproduce the issue with your code and PDF, and the cause is fairly trivial, cf. the edit to my question, the new section "On the actual issue".

Comment: @mkl I have no words. after adding that one line now it works fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On the original logging related question

One option is to activate the console logger from code, at the start of your program put:

```
// create properties
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["showDateTime"] = "true";
properties["level"] = "All";

// set Adapter
Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);
```

E.g. for the following test

```
[Test]
public void CreateLogOutput()
{
    // create properties
    NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
    properties["showDateTime"] = "true";
    properties["level"] = "All";

    // set Adapter
    Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);

    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader));
    logger.Error("Testing an error log output", new Exception("The exception message"));
}
```

one gets an output like this:

```
27.06.2018 17:07:37 [ERROR] iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader - Testing an error log output
=======================================================(inner most exception)===
 (1) System.Exception
================================================================================
Method        :  <unavailable>
Type          :  <unavailable>
Assembly      :  <unavailable>
Assembly Path :  <unavailable>
Source        :  
Thread        :  15 'NonParallelWorker'
Helplink      :  

Message:
"The exception message"

Stack Trace:

================================================================================
```

#### On the actual issue

After you added the code to the question, the issue became clear: You forgot to close the `PdfDocument pdfDocument`. Thus, everything works alright, nothing is logged, merely the changes are not written to file as the PDF document object is not closed. Simply close it after the `cleaner.CleanUp()` call:

```
PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, cleanUpLocations);
cleaner.CleanUp();
pdfDocument.Close();
```

The result now is some 34KB in size and displays like this:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I've tried Your solution, but nothing happened. I've added full example code. Same code worked fine when written in iTextSharp 5.5.13, after rewriting to iText 7.1.2 I get not working 1 KB PDF as output. pdfSweep is addon that (to my knowledge) requires license, it should throw error when license is not set, but nothing happens.

Comment: If you run my test `CreateLogOutput` above, do you then get the output I got?

Comment: Yes, I see output in console, same with nlog config from my question, but somehow I don't see any errors from iText7

Comment: @Misiu *"Yes, I see output in console, same with nlog config from my question, but somehow I don't see any errors from iText7"* - That means that the logging configurations are correct but iText7 simply does not log anything when running your code.